# Документация по Objective-C для Mac Os X

Tags: objective-c

Добрый день. Можете посоветовать ресурсы с информацией, мануалами и уроками по Objective-c для mac os x. Желательно на русском, на английском тоже подойдут.

Буду премного благодарен.

Answer (score 3):

Если серьезно, то начните с [lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/iOS-tutorials/Core-Data-iOS-OS-X/101461-2.html) там мужичек - ваще мужик. По секрету есть куча докс в XCode, если купить сертификат девелопера.

Comment: Мужичка зовут Simon Allardice. Он Мегаотец в смысле и знаний и педагогики

Comment: Даааа таких бы преподов да побольше... Ваще сказка его слушать.

Answer (score 2):

Есть [курс](https://u.hexlet.org/courses/4) по разработке под OSX на русском. Еще можешь успеть.
обучения под xCode ObjectiveC

Comment: Спасибо, я уже на этом курсе, с того момента как он только запустился, но там маловато информации.

Comment: курс то платный.

Answer (score 2):

Есть книга на русском - Аарон Хиллегас - Objective-C. Программирование для iOS и MacOS. Книга вышла в этом году. Если хорошо поискать, можно найти в электронном виде.
На английском этого добра навалом по-моему. Достаточно погуглить.

Answer (score 2):

[OSXDev](http://osxdev.ru) - Ресурс для iOS и Mac OS разработчиков на русском. На сайте есть видео курс для начинающих на русском языка http://osxdev.ru/blog/screencasts/

Также есть много полезных статей для начинающих разработчиков http://osxdev.ru/tag/начинающим/